# ssh -T hanging when trying to access an AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have an AWS EC2 instance and I can ssh into it fine, but I want to use ssh -T so that my keys are shared for github access and so on, but ssh -T hangs after login.

Has anyone experienced this or any ideas about how to fix?

One thing I have done is stick verbose mode in .bashrc and it seems to get stuck after this output

```
 + export -f module
 + export -f switchml
 + '[' 5 -ge 3 ']'
 + [[ hxB =~ i ]]
 + [[ ! :/usr/local/cuda/bin:/opt/amazon/openmpi/bin/:/opt/amazon/efa/bin/:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin: =~ :/usr/bin: ]]
 + '[' '!' -n x ']'
++ manpath
 + [[ ! :/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man:: =~ :/usr/share/man: ]]
 + unset _mlcode _mlret
 + '[' -n '' ']'
```

one thing I notice is that with `-T` the $PS1 appears to be different and so the first line of the bashrc file sources an additional file:

```
[ -z "$PS1" ] && source /etc/profile.d/dlami.sh
```

but I'm not really sure how that's all related ...

Answer (score 0):

okay, so this was all a confusion about ssh flags - should have been `ssh -a`